# Magento Customer Dataflow Profile Model Override

Tags: magento

I am writing one extension in Magento that need to override Magento customer adapter class namely "Mage_Customer_Model_Convert_Adapter_Customer". But when I rewrite it and the profile it is showing me below error.

Fatal error: Class ' Bs_Crm_Model_Customer ' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\mag\app\code\core\Mage\Dataflow\Model\Convert\Action\Abstract.php on line 182

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: what a rubbish ?

Comment: What do you mean?